# Is jumping in snow piles the same as throwing snowballs?

Tags: snoopys-street-fair

I got the recent update for Snoopy's Street Fair, and the goal that used to be "jump in 50 leaf piles" changed to "jump in 50 snow piles".

I figured it would work like the leaf piles - tap them, Snoopy runs over, and hops in. Simple enough. However, when I tap the snow piles, Snoopy runs over, steps on the pile, and throws a snowball at someone.

I have noticed that the progress meter hasn't moved for the 50 snow piles goal since the update - is this related to the fact that Snoopy is throwing snow instead of jumping in it? Or is my game just bugged somehow?

Comment: +1 for having a title that made me click through to see what the hell this was about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're different things.  I believe you'll have to [change Snoopy's outfit](http://getsatisfaction.com/beeline_games/topics/snow_pile_how_do_i_get_snoopy_to_jump_in_it) if you want him to stop throwing snowballs.  Apparently he throws a snowball instead of jumping in the pile if he's wearing the Santa suit.